# Why Intellij Idea sometimes refuses to @Autowire source beans to tests?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, configuration, scope, javabeans

It's a popular error (or annoying bug?) - when some project were imported from maven or gradle model the ide treats source files related to test files as if they are in separate project in sense of Spring configuration. 
Suppose you have

in your source folders
**mypackage/MyBean.java**

in your test folders
**mypackage/MyBeanTest.java**
in which you

> import mypackage/MyBean.java

just OK

and if you try to `@Autoware MyBeanTest` - it fails.

If you move your MyBean.java to your source folders, everything @Autoware just OK, but that's not what was intended.

My idea is something is wrong with workspace.xml or similar, but i'm not that deft with Idea.

How could we fix it?

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @y.bedrov i took a well known demo project https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-events and the results were the same in several idea 2016, 2017 and 2018.2 EAP versions - 
https://snag.gy/BkvTNV.jpg.